# How to add break or return in ternary?

Tags: php, if-statement, return, break, ternary

i want to add break; or return inside the ternary but i have no idea how. on the 'more option' page where i used similar code but instead of ternary i used 'if and else' where i could easly add break and that worked fine.

now the problem is without the break it shows double of the users (see the image below). 
can anyone show me the route to fix this problem?, thanks in advance.

```
            case "playerList":
        $array = array();
        foreach($commands->getPlayers() as $key => $row) {
            foreach($commands->getMutedOrNot() as $row1) {
array_push($array, array(
    "<a href=\"player.php?player=".$key."\">".$key."</a>",
    $row,
    "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?ban=".$key."\">Ban</a>",
    "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?kick=".$key."\">Kick</a>",
    ($row1 == 1) ?
        "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?unmute=".$key."\">Unmute</a>"
        :
        "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?mute=".$key."\">mute</a>",
    "<a class=\"btn btn-success\" href=\"player.php?player=".$key."\">More Options</a>"
));
            }
        }
        $array = json_encode(array("data" => $array));
        print_r($array);
        break;
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkSDL.png)

What i try to do:

```
            case "playerList":
        $array = array();
        foreach($commands->getPlayers() as $key => $row) {
            foreach($commands->getMutedOrNot() as $row1) {
array_push($array, array(
    "<a href=\"player.php?player=".$key."\">".$key."</a>",
    $row,
    "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?ban=".$key."\">Ban</a>",
    "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?kick=".$key."\">Kick</a>",
    ($row1 == 1) ?
        "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?unmute=".$key."\">Unmute</a>"
break;
        :
        "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?mute=".$key."\">mute</a>",
break;
    "<a class=\"btn btn-success\" href=\"player.php?player=".$key."\">More Options</a>"
));
            }
        }
        $array = json_encode(array("data" => $array));
        print_r($array);
        break;
```

Comment: you dont need to add the `break`, its for the `switch`

Comment: Could it be because of the foreach inside of the foreach, Maybe try and combine?

Comment: how can i stop the code if ($row1 == 1) ?  [content] and then it stops?

Comment: The is an example where ternary shouldn't be used. You can't use `break` in an assignment. You need to use a standard conditional and use `break` in that.

Comment: after the `array_push(...)` add `if($row1==1) break;`